# Get version of specific plugin via Maven help plugin's goal evaluate

Tags: maven, maven-help-plugin

Is there a way to use `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression` to get the version number of a specific plugin? The compiler plugin for example?

Comment: The first question which comes into my mind reading this is: Why do you need the version of a plugin? Furthermore it is possible something like this: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.pluginManagement.plugins[0].version -DforceStdout=true -q` but this requires to know that it is defined like this?...

Comment: I have serveral projects where I have to update a specific plugin on a regular basis. Therefore I would like to write a shell script which updates the plugin and generates the correct commit message with the previous and the new version number of the plugin.

Comment: That's what I expected. Currently I'm working on a way to do that automatically as well...What about (in the first step) to parse the output of versions-maven-plugin......?

Comment: I can support you in doing so? I already had a look at the source code.